# JSF 2 AJAX Response Cache

Tags: ajax, http, jsf, caching

When I use JSF 2 Ajax, how do I control whether the response is cacheable.  If that's possible, how do I control the expry date of the AJAX response? Thanks!  -- Charlie

Answer (score 0):

As is typical for JSF applications, the caching headers are set via a `Filter`, which is part of the Servlet layer. For this layer there is no automatic difference between a normal request and an AJAX request.

JSF however marks requests as AJAX requests by means of the `javax.faces.partial.ajax` request parameter. (see JSF spec section 14.2.4)

If you thus want to specifically control the response headers for all JSF AJAX requests, you would do something like:

```
@WebFilter(filterName="httpHeaders", urlPatterns="/*")
public class HTTPHeaders extends Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (request.getParameter("javax.faces.partial.ajax") != null) {
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "...");
            response.setDateHeader ("Expires", "...");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "...");
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pssh, the `HttpFilter` is not part of the servlet API ;) In our project it's a homegrown and convenient HTTP layer over the bare `javax.servlet.Filter` API.

Comment: Haha, the names we choose look too much like official names. But shame on me, I'll change the answer ;)